# Most JS buttons on SE and SO stopped working this weekend

Tags: bug, login, javascript, firefox

I use Stack Overflow and the related sites on a semi-daily basis. Today I found that the following no longer works (the buttons do nothing):

- "Log in using Google" on at least rpg.se (I can work around this by clicking "More login options" and filling in the OpenID in the text box)
- The StackExchange drop-down and the two icons to the right of it on the top toolbar on rpg.se and workplace.se

The icon to the left of the URL showed a warning sign for workplace.se and tex.se in Firefox. When clicking it I got a "This website does not supply ownership information." message. After reloading using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> the icon changed to the familiar lock on workplace.se, but *not* on tex.se. The voting buttons now work on *both* sites, so maybe this is unrelated?

I'm currently using HTTPS Everywhere. Is there a known issue with this?

Comment: Yes that's an issue, because HTTPS is not fully supported yet. You are likely getting mixed content that is causing certain pieces of the site to not load correctly. If you're not using standard HTTP, then you're not *officially* supported. When it is officially supported, there will very likely be a blog about it.